# Sum of series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\cdot (1- a)^{k-1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would go around finding the sum of the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\cdot (1- a)^{k-1}$$ Any help is appreciated, I bumped into this series while solving a question, and I know the series converges for $|1-a|<1$, so please do assume that.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}$, so differentiating gives $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$. Set $x=1-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: integrate and use a geometric series expansion.

Here's some elaboration:
$$
\int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\cdot (1- a)^{k-1}da=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int k(1-a)^{k-1}da=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-a)^k=\frac{1}{1-(1-a)}=\frac{1}{a}
$$

Comment: How will integrating help here? I am not too familiar with series summing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot(1-a)^{k-1} $ and note $(1-a)S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot(1-a)^{k}$. Substract them to get the partial sum and take $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Sorry, that is not helping. After subtracting the two, you just arrive with the same expression for the partial sum again.